# How to pass IPv4 address to terraform provisioner local-exec

Tags: terraform

I was trying to do

> terraform apply

but getting below error

> 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> - digitalocean_droplet.testvm[0]: Resource 'digitalocean_droplet.testvm' not found for variable
>     'digitalocean_droplet.testvm.ipv4_address'
>
> Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
>   Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with any
>   resources that successfully completed. Please address the error above
>   and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure.

How can I pass the public ip of the created droplet to provisioner local-exec command.

Below is my **.tf** file

```
provider "digitalocean" {
  token = "----TOKEN----"
}

resource "digitalocean_droplet" "testvm" {
    count = "10"
    name = "do-instance-${count.index}"
    image = "ubuntu-16-04-x64"
    size = "512mb"
    region = "nyc3"
    ipv6 = true
    private_networking = false
    ssh_keys = [
      "----SSH KEY----"
    ]
    provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "fab production deploy ${digitalocean_droplet.testvm.ipv4_address}"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For local-exec provisioner you can make use of the `self` keyword. In this case it would be `{self.ipv4_address}`.

My guess is that your snippet would've worked if you don't put `count=10` in the `testvm` droplet. You can also make use of `${count.index}`

More info: https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/

Also, found [this github issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/398#issuecomment-59631221) that might be helpful to you.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Andy for the reply. I want to deploy 10 droplets that's why passed count=10

Comment: Yeah, I figured. the github issue that I found address exactly your problem.

Comment: It worked ({self.ipv4_address}). Thank you so much Andy, you saved my day :)

Comment: Nice. Glad I can help @rahulb

Comment: You do need the `self` regardless of the count.